# ActiveJDBC failed to determine Model class name while findFirst but not while insert

Tags: java, spring-boot, activejdbc

While debugging in eclipse below spring boot application is working fine inserting a record in the table but is not while doing findFirst, giving me: `failed to determine Model class name, are you sure models have been instrumented?`

**Gradle:**

```
plugins {
    (...)
    id 'java'
    id "de.schablinski.activejdbc-gradle-plugin" version "1.2" apply false 
}

(...)

dependencies {

    implementation group: 'org.javalite', name: 'activejdbc', version: '1.4.11'
    implementation group: 'org.javalite', name: 'activejdbc-instrumentation', version: '1.4.11' 

    (...)
}

/** Task: Instrument ActiveJdbc models **/
    task activeJdbcInstrumentation() {
    apply plugin: 'de.schablinski.activejdbc-gradle-plugin'
}

build.dependsOn(activeJdbcInstrumentation)
```

**Java**

```
Base.open(dataSource);

try {
    TestConJavaLite model = new TestConJavaLite();          
    model.setString("ID", UUID.randomUUID());
    model.setString("Column1", UUID.randomUUID());
    model.setString("Column2", UUID.randomUUID());
    model.setString("Column3", UUID.randomUUID());
    model.setString("Column4", UUID.randomUUID());
    model.setString("Column5", UUID.randomUUID());
    model.setString("Column5", UUID.randomUUID());
    model.setString("Column6", UUID.randomUUID());
    model.setString("Column7", UUID.randomUUID());
    model.setString("Column8", UUID.randomUUID());
    model.setString("Column9", UUID.randomUUID());
    model.insert(); // --> Works fine

    model = model.findFirst("ID = 1"); // --> Gives error
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}       

if(Base.hasConnection()) {
    Base.close();
}
```

What I don't understand is why is giving that error just for the `findFirst` and not for the `insert`. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The  way  Instrumentation works is described here: https://javalite.io/instrumentation

Basically, instrumentation copies byte code  of   *static* methods from class `Model` into your class. The instance methods are untouched. The `findFirst()` method is static  and if you want to use it, you need instrumentation. The `insert()`  is an instance method, and hence  does not require instrumentation.

Comment: It works if I run the project from the command line, but not from the eclipse IDE, from there it gives me the above error, any idea why? Or is supposed to work if I execute it from the eclipse IDE as well? Also the way I'm doing the instrumentation isn't the right way? The video you have explaining it seems to be broken.

Comment: @Somebody, the video is working for me. Here is a direct link to Youtube; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHXJXzZNKCU&feature=emb_logo. It is possible Eclipse recompiles classes, and erases instrumentation. Please  this page for configuring Eclipse: https://javalite.io/eclipseIntegration

Comment: @Somebody if you think this answer helps, mark it as correct and upvote, please

Comment: @Somebody, the video was fixed, thanks for alerting to the issue.